# list possible upgrades in apk?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, alpine-linux

I have a pinephone and I want to upgrade my packages, but every time I do, my phone ends up unbootable. I am running postmarket OS; the package manager is apk. I just want to list the available upgrades, but not install them. I will select upgrades manually.

I read the [apk Alpine Linux wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management), but I didn't see what I'm looking for there.

For some reason, postmarket OS felt the inclusion of manpages was entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, update the repositories to fetch the latest updates with:

`apk update`

Then, try to simulate the upgrade with:

`apk upgrade --simulate`

You can do it in one shot:
`apk update && apk upgrade --simulate`

If you want to simulate the upgrade of one specific package:

`apk add -u $package --simulate`

where of course `$package` is the package you want to upgrade.

Hope this helps.

.: Francesco